# matplotlib bar chart with pandas dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a very simple bar chart with matplotlib, the underlying data beeing in a pd.dataframe with datetime timestamps as an index

However when trying

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(data.index, data[subset])
```

I get the Error: 
**TypeError**: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

A working workaround might be

```
ax.bar(data.index, [i[0] for i in data[subset].values.tolist()])
```

but I am very confused why I cant use pd.dataframe as input value for a bar chart. If I use the exact same code `plot` instead of `bar`, everythings works just fine. 
I really want to use plt.bar here as I am building a bigger plot and this is only a part of it, so df.bar doesnt help.

Comment: Do you mind to provide an [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Use pandas plot with `df[subset].plot.bar(ax=ax)`

Comment: Check the answer below, you need to do something similar

Answer (score 0):

You are really close:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'lab':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'val':[10, 30, 20]})
  ax = df.plot.bar(x='lab', y='val', rot=0)
```

You need to invoke the df and call the plot function on it.

Comment: thanks I know this might work but the thing is I don't want to change the structure of my dataframe as it's part of a bigger plot. I just want to create a bar plot with it, also my x axis data is within the index and I dont want to add another column as this would mess up the rest of the code.
But I think the problem with ax.bar() was that my slice of the dataframe was still a dataframe and not a series.

Comment: This is an example, this is not changing your dataframe at all. 
The first line is showing that there is a sample dataframe, which in this case is your dataframe coming from whereever, does not really matter, the second line is invoking the plot functionality of the dataframe. That is the one you need to try !